How is では used here?

だから２人がライバル関係では絶対嫌だろうなって

I'm wondering, what does では do here?
The only way I could think of it was "if/when" or "as a state" but let me know if it is wrong.

There seems to be nothing wrong with interpreting this では as "if/when" (or だと).

だから2人がライバル関係では絶対嫌だろうなって
So, I guess [someone] would definitely hate it if the two are rivals.

